# Using the 'az vm run-command' with a .ps1 file

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli2, runcommand

I have an issue with the `az vm run-command`.

I have got it working inline as follows:

```
$resource_name="winsecagentdev2"
$resource_group="russellmccloydev"
```

and:

```
az vm run-command invoke `
-g "${resource_group}" `
-n "${resource_name}" `
--command-id 'RunPowerShellScript' `
--scripts "Write-Output 'testing russ'"
```

It works.

But when I try to use a .ps1 file:

```
az vm run-command invoke `
-g "${resource_group}" `
-n "${resource_name}" `
--command-id 'RunPowerShellScript' `
--scripts @{'hello.ps1'} `
--parameters @{ "test" = "russell" }
```

I get this issue:

[image]

The documentation says this:

[image]

So I am kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the file in your VM and use the format below:

```
--scripts "C:\test\hello.ps1"
```

result:

[image]

Comment: ok but when I put my script on the destination machine at c:\getAccessToVM.ps1 if says file not found. It's actually looking on the caller machine for the file and not the destination.

Comment: @RuSs It works fine on my side, could you provide the error message? Or try the path like I mentioned? ps: my vm is windows OS.

Comment: Will do but can you share you hello.ps1 script? maybe ill start with that and work backwards. Mine is also a windows VM

Comment: @RuSs Just `Write-Host hello` in my script, you could see the `"message":"hello"` in the output.

Comment: ok.. and are you calling az vm run-command invoke from a remote machine like your laptop?

Comment: @RuSs I called the command in my PC, not the VM, the script file is in the VM.

Comment: yes very helpful. It's working now. but sometimes it takes a long time and is intermittent with regard to success rate. But all good, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try to put the file with the following format:
**--scripts "@hello.ps1"`**

[image: Screenshot]

[image: hello.ps1]

Comment: What do you mean by *"put the file"*?

Comment: This also works if you're on Windows and using PowerShell to run stuff on Linux VMs.

Answer (score 1):

To run a script from a remote machine to a Linux VM in Azure, use:

```
az vm run-command invoke myResourceGroup -n myVm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "@quality-check.pl"
```

I had copied the `quality-check.pl` script in my current location on the remote machine.

Comment: did you upload quality-check.pl n server?